# Android Studio Gradle not using transitive dependencies

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, dependencies, transitive-dependency

Having experienced this problem in a separate project, I made a test project to verify the issue.

1. Opening Android Studio 3.0, I created a new basic project.  Its main module was called `app`.
2. I added a library module, called `libraryone`.
3. In `libraryone`, I added a dependency to Gson, and added a single class with a single static method using Gson.
4. In `app`, I added a dependency to `libraryone`.  I tested it plain, as well as with `transitive = true`, as the internet seemed to vaguely concur that doing so might help.  (It did not.)
5. In `app`, in `MainActivity`, I used the class from `libraryone`.  This worked (as long as I didn't have `transitive = false` set, instead).
6. However, I cannot reference Gson from `MainActivity` itself.  It gives a "Cannot resolve symbol 'Gson'" error, both from Android Studio, as well as from the command line Gradle.  This is...unusual and aggravating, as it means you have to repeat common dependencies all throughout a group of projects, and the classes are included in the output anyway.  Surely either I'm doing something wrong, or this is a bug?

My code is as follows:

MainActivity.java (in `app`)

```
package com.erhannis.test.dependencytest;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.erhannis.test.libraryone.LibClass;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String s = LibClass.convert(new Object());
        System.out.println("out: " + s);

        new com.google.gson.Gson(); // This line gives a compile-time error: "Cannot resolve symbol 'Gson'"
    }
}
```

LibClass.java (in `libraryone`)

```
package com.erhannis.test.libraryone;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class LibClass {
    public static String convert(Object o) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        return gson.toJson(o);
    }
}
```

build.gradle (`app`)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.erhannis.test.dependencytest"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

    implementation (project(path: ':libraryone'))
}
```

build.gradle (`libraryone`)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is because you declared the transitive dependency as `implementation`. Use `api` instead of `implementation` change:

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
```

to:

```
api 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
```

The reason why you should declare the transitive dependency in your library can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#dependency_configurations)

Comment: This does not work for me. Can you please explain me how does it work ?

Comment: @KulsDroid you can difference between them [here](https://blog.mindorks.com/implementation-vs-api-in-gradle-3-0-494c817a6fa)

Answer (score 7):

You are using:

```
implementation (project(path: ':libraryone'))
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
```

Check the [official doc](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#new_configurations):

> When your module configures an `implementation` dependency, it's letting Gradle know that the module does not want to leak the dependency to other modules at compile time. That is, the dependency is available to other modules only at runtime.

Here you can find a very [good blog](https://blog.mindorks.com/implementation-vs-api-in-gradle-3-0-494c817a6fa) about it.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for this is to create a private Github/Gitlab repository for the aar dependency. You can also make it public if you want. The aar file does not contain transitive dependencies when used locally. We need to publish it somewhere with the .pom file. Here's how to do it,

1. create a personal access token in Github

> Github -> Settings -> Developer Settings -> Personal Access token - with write:packages / read:packages access level
>
> (create two tokens if you need to distribute privately

2. Add `id 'maven-publish'` to plugins in module level gradle
3. Add the below code to module level gradle

   ```
   task sourceJar(type: Jar) {
       from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
       archiveClassifier.set("sources")
   }

    publishing {
        publications {
            bar(MavenPublication) {
                groupId 'com.your'
                artifactId 'artifact'
                version '1.0'
                artifact sourceJar
                artifact("$buildDir/outputs/aar/YourLibraryName-release.aar")
                pom.withXml {
                    final dependenciesNode = asNode().appendNode('dependencies')
                    ext.addDependency = { Dependency dep, String scope ->
                        if (dep.group == null || dep.version == null || dep.name == null || dep.name == "unspecified")
                            return
                        final dependencyNode = dependenciesNode.appendNode('dependency')
                        dependencyNode.appendNode('groupId', dep.group)
                        dependencyNode.appendNode('artifactId', dep.name)
                        dependencyNode.appendNode('version', dep.version)
                        dependencyNode.appendNode('scope', scope)
                        if (!dep.transitive) {
                            final exclusionNode = dependencyNode.appendNode('exclusions').appendNode('exclusion')
                            exclusionNode.appendNode('groupId', '*')
                            exclusionNode.appendNode('artifactId', '*')
                        } else if (!dep.properties.excludeRules.empty) {
                            final exclusionNode = dependencyNode.appendNode('exclusions').appendNode('exclusion')
                            dep.properties.excludeRules.each { ExcludeRule rule ->
                                exclusionNode.appendNode('groupId', rule.group ?: '*')
                                exclusionNode.appendNode('artifactId', rule.module ?: '*')
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    configurations.compile.getDependencies().each { dep -> addDependency(dep, "compile") }
                    configurations.api.getDependencies().each { dep -> addDependency(dep, "compile") }
                    configurations.implementation.getDependencies().each { dep -> addDependency(dep, "runtime") }
                }
            }
        }

        repositories {
            maven {
                name = "GitHubPackages"
                url = uri("https://maven.pkg.github.com/GITHUB_USERID/REPOSITORY")
                credentials {
                    username = "GITHUB_USERID" // Better if you use env variable
                    password = "WRITE_ACCESS_TOKEN"
                }
            }
        }
    }
   ```
4. In the Gradle toolbar you can find **publish** under the **publishing** subdirectory in your library module directory. ( Make sure to build the aar from **build->build** in module directory before publish)
5. To use it in your project, 
    add following to your **app level gradle file** inside android{ }tag

   ```
    repositories {
        maven {
            name = "GitHubPackages"
            url = uri("https://maven.pkg.github.com/GITHUB_USERID/REPOSITORY")
            credentials {
                username = "GITHUB_USERID" // Better if you use env variable 
                password = "READ_ACCESS_TOKEN"
            }
        }
    }
   ```
6. Finally in dependencies

   ```
    implementation 'com.your:artifact:1.0'
   ```

*Gitlab is also pretty similar to this